# Using "argv" to pass image files C++

Tags: c++, image, program-entry-point

I am currently testing a program of image segmentation and need to somehow pass a test image file in the main program as shown below. Been searching for a while. I would appreciate an example of how to use or replace the "argv" with the test image file and consequently produce an output file. Much appreciate your guidance!

http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/[^]

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 6) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s sigma k min input(ppm) output(ppm)\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  float sigma = atof(argv[1]);
  float k = atof(argv[2]);
  int min_size = atoi(argv[3]);

  printf("loading input image.\n");
  image<rgb> *input = loadPPM(argv[4]);

  printf("processing\n");
  int num_ccs; 
  image<rgb> *seg = segment_image(input, sigma, k, min_size, &num_ccs); 
  savePPM(seg, argv[5]);

  printf("got %d components\n", num_ccs);
  printf("done! uff...thats hard work.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what you tried, and how it failed.

Comment: if there are spaces in the file path you should use it with Quotation marks. like: `"path\to\file name.ext"`

Comment: Rob Kennedy, I tried replacing argv[4] with the image file path and argv[5] with the name of the output image. I also replaced sigma, k and min_size with values given in an example. But this didn't produce any output image file upon running the program. It never got the stage: printf("got %d components\n", num_ccs);
  printf("done! uff...thats hard work.\n");

Answer (score 3):

Just provide the name of the image file as an argument to the program.

`a.out 1.0 1.0 100 Input Output`

`Input` and `Output` are paths to an input image and output image respectively.

More info:
[What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: I right-clicked on my project in Solution Explorer > Configuration Properties> Debugging. In Command Arguments I typed in:

"C:\ Projects\segment\Debug>segment.exe" 0.5 500 20 
"C:\ Projects\segment\segment\image.ppm" 
"C:\ Projects\segment\segment\output.ppm"

trying to make sure I didn't leave any unnecessary spaces. 
However, argc = 7 when outputted though it should be 6.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this problem, thanks.

Comment: @DavidSpears Don't include the program as an argument